# angular2-material used with systemjs for Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have followed the TUTORIAL: TOUR OF HEROES on [enter link description here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)

I'm trying to add angular2-material to it but i'm not able to get the CSS to work properly. What am I missing or doing wrong?

[my systemjs configuration](https://github.com/skiarn/heroes-example-angular2/blob/master/systemjs.config.js)

I have made following configuration in app.component.ts

```
import {MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular2-material/list/list';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:
  ....
  directives: [HeroDetailComponent,MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES],
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you importing all the directives you are using, for eg:

```
import {MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular2-material/card';
import {MdInput} from '@angular2-material/input';
import {MdCheckbox} from '@angular2-material/checkbox';
```

[See the full list of Angular2 Material Directives here](https://github.com/angular/material2/wiki/Design-doc-directory)

Comment: I'm only so far trying to use  md-list and md-list-item. Therefore im only trying to use MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES.

Answer (score 0):

As latest angular2 and angular2 material have changed their way of systemjs setting, I couldn't find any from internet, but finally I've found how to do.

Get latest version(2.1.2) of ng2 from  angular 2 quickstart, 
add these two in your package.json

```
 "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-3",
 "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.33"
```

Add to your systemjs.config.js as:

```
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',
    :
    '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js',
    :
```

change your app.module.ts from :

```
@NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule],
```

to :

```
 @NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule, MaterialModule.forRoot()],
```

Also you can add some css inside index.html. For more detail, pls see https://github.com/Longfld/ng2QuickStartForBeginning